# Launching Docker container with Ansible gives "command not found"

Tags: docker, ansible

I'm trying to create a container from within a playbook that would execute some terraform code, but as soon as the container is created the first command I ask of it `apt update` gives me the error message on exit `/bin/bash: line 1: apt update && apt install -y build-essential && bundle install && terraspace check_setup && terraspace up rds -y: command not found`.
The weirdest part, is that it used to work well, but since we updated from ansible `2.10.X` to ansible `2.12.8` this error appeared.
Here's a the code use to create the container:

```yaml
- name: Launch Docker container with Terraspace image
  register: container_terraspace_apply_result
  community.docker.docker_container:
    name: "terraspace-test"
    image: a-private-ubuntu-base-terraform-image
    working_dir: /opt/terraform
    volumes:
      - "/home/terraform:/opt/terraform:rw"
      - "/home/.aws:/root/.aws:ro"
    command_handling: correct
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash"]
    command: [
      "-l",
      "-c",
      "'apt update && apt install -y build-essential && bundle install && terraspace check_setup && terraspace up rds -y'"
    ]
    env:
      REGION: "eu-west-1"
      AWS_REGION: "eu-west-1"
      TS_ENV: "staging"
      AWS_PROFILE: "terraform-staging"
```

I found out that if I only do `"'apt'"` I do get the aptr help output you would get when typing it with no arguments, so the binary path is good, the only problems seems to be the space after it ???

Is there something I'm missing here ? I've been looking around and couldn't find a solution to my issue.

Thank you !

Comment: `apt` might be found but you need to check if the other binaries are also within `$PATH`. So check `terraspace` and `bundle` by themselves.

Comment: It seems like there's one more layer of quotes than you need in the last command word.  Since you're using an array syntax each item is already a separate shell word, so you don't need to also quote the command inside the option to `sh -c`.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out it was the `command_handling` option that needed to be set to `compatibility` !